# Nested key value pair grouping into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an Object with nested key value pair as:

```
Products:{
 Clip:{
   today_entry: 0,
   today_sold: 0
 },
 Necklace:
 {
   today_entry: 0,
   today_sold: 2
 }
}
```

I want to loop through the Objects Clip ad Necklace and group the values as per their inner keys i.e. today_entry, today_sold into the format:

```
{
 today_entry : [0,0],
 today_sold : [0,2]
}
```

I tried doing it using Object.entries but since it is nested I'm not able to get the inner keys. Could anyone please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Be careful that Objects are not ordered, Clip does not come necessarily prior to Necklace  (unless you give some ordering criteria that you did not tell us) so there is no meaning wanting an output with arrays (that are, well, ordered)

Comment: This is the api response received which I want to present it in a combination chart, so order of the objects doesn't really matter @Zzirconium

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method to create an object with [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get values from object:

```
const result = Object.values(products).reduce((a, c) => {
    for (const key in c) {
       a[key] = a[key] || [];
       a[key].push(c[key]);
    }
    return a;
},{});
```

An example:

```js
let products  = {
 Clip:{
   today_entry: 0,
   today_sold: 0
 },
 Necklace:
 {
   today_entry: 0,
   today_sold: 2
 }
}

const result = Object.values(products).reduce((a, c) => {
  for (const key in c) {
a[key] = a[key] || [];
a[key].push(c[key]);
  }
  return a;
},{});



console.log(result)
```

Comment: very elegant solution. But again I think the OP wanting this out as an array is a mistake as there is no guarantee Products keys will be reduced in a deterministic order.

Comment: @Zzirconium thanks for the kind words! It means to me a lot! Let's wait OP to know what he actually wants! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `reudce`:

```js
const products = {
 Clip:{
   today_entry: 0,
   today_sold: 0,
 },
 Necklace:
 {
   today_entry: 0,
   today_sold: 2,
 },
};

const result = Object.keys(products).reduce((ac, key) => ({
 today_entry: [ ...ac.today_entry, products[key].today_entry],
 today_sold: [ ...ac.today_sold, products[key].today_sold],
}), { today_entry: [], today_sold: []});

console.log(result);
```

In case the order of the values in the arrays are important you should also sort the keys the way you want.

Comment: Very good solution. What does this ...ac.today entry?

Comment: @Alex it is called [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) which in this case spreads the values from an array into the other newly created array.

Answer (score 1):

```
const products = {
 Clip:{
   today_entry: 0,
   today_sold: 0
 },
 Necklace:
 {
   today_entry: 0,
   today_sold: 2
 }
}

const result = {};

for(item in products) {
  for (action in products[item]) {
    result[action]= result[action]||[];
    result[action].push(products[item][action])
  }
}

console.log(result)
//{ today_entry: [ 0, 0 ], today_sold: [ 0, 2 ] }
```